# Why is there a 6 character edit limit for edit suggestions?

Tags: discussion

I am beginning to get very irritated by the minimum six character edit limit. It's my habit to try to fix misspellings and clear grammatical errors in questions, in order to improve site quality. Quite often I get the message telling me that I can't do that, because an edit has to be six characters. Then there is a helpful message saying "is there something else in the question that could be improved?". Well, no there isn't. That's why I'm making this one.

What is the rationale behind the 6 character limit? Can't the servers handle small edits? Are we trying to discourage people from correcting questions?

Answer (score 5):

It is what it is.  See [this question on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/were-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-se-sites).

> As a < 2k rep user, you should make reasonably substantive edits. The approval cost for your edit is not free, as it costs the attention of one or more users who have to look at your edit and think about it. This cost is high for extremely trivial edits.
>
> This will not be changing.
>
> If you want to make single-character trivial edits, earn 2k rep.
>
> ([Source: Jeff's answer from the same question on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/were-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-se-sites/77257#77257).)

Also, questions pertaining to the general functionality of the platform itself belong on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 3):

> is there something else in the question that could be improved?". Well, no there isn't.

The post is otherwise *so perfect* that it cannot be improved in any way? Quite rare indeed..

> What is the rationale behind the 6 character limit?

Suggested edits have to be vetted by other community members, so we ask that you please make them substantive edits.

If you wish to make trivial 1 character edits on the site, you will need to earn 2,000 reputation first.

Comment: Dang, beat me to it.  How do you do that?! ;)

Comment: One thing I don't like about the 6 character rule is if I change 100 characters in the title, but only 2 in the body, it tells me I need to change at least 6 characters.    I end up reverting my body change and keeping only the title change.

Comment: @George: Maybe Jeff has some magic of "Jon Skeet" at Stackoverflow  rubbed off him.

Comment: Indeed. I just saw a typo at math.se, a simple one letter error. My OCD said to fix it. My <2K rep there said 'can't.' But, my 2K rep here let me fix the typo in your reply.